# How to create a single record from a group within time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help with below SQL challenge. I got SQL server table with three columns item no, start & End time stamps and please see sample data below.
Requirement is to find group of transactions within 20 min time frame(highlighted below in BOLD) for the same itemno and then, create one new single row with start time stamp from first row and end time stamp is from last row in that data set.
Can someone please help with this?

Source sample data :

```
ItemNo     StartTstp               EndTstp
1100    2018-10-10 5:47:00      2018-10-10 6:28:00
1100    2018-10-10 7:47:00      2018-10-10 7:48:00
1100    2018-10-10 7:48:00      2018-10-10 7:50:00
1100    2018-10-10 7:50:00      2018-10-10 7:53:00
1100    2018-10-10 13:10:00     2018-10-10 13:20:00
1100    2018-10-10 16:10:00     2018-10-10 16:30:00
1101    2018-10-10 9:50:00      2018-10-10 9:53:00
```

Output:

```
ItemNo  StartTstp               EndTstp
1100    2018-10-10 5:47:00      2018-10-10 6:28:00
1100    2018-10-10 7:47:00      2018-10-10 7:53:00
1100    2018-10-10 13:10:00     2018-10-10 13:20:00
1100    2018-10-10 16:10:00     2018-10-10 16:30:00
1101    2018-10-10 9:50:00      2018-10-10 9:53:00
```

Thanks.

[screenshots of sample & result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w2zJ.png)

Comment: Search for "Gaps and Islands problem". This is a good place to start: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/

Comment: We would also need to know your exact SQL Server version.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. version is 2014. Also, i will read & try to understand "Introduction to Gaps and Islands Analysis".

Comment: Hi Dale, with my limited skills, i was only managed to produce one single row if very first row & very last row within 20 min. time frame. but, i couldn't find a solution, if the transactions some where in middle within 20 min. like in my provided example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how I understand the question you could try this CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t1.ItemNo,
        t1.StartTstp,
        MAX(t2.EndTstp) AS EndTstp
    FROM YourTable AS t1
        JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON
            t1.ItemNo = t2.ItemNo
            AND DATEDIFF(MI, t1.StartTstp, t2.StartTstp) BETWEEN 0 AND 20
    GROUP BY
        t1.ItemNo,
        t1.StartTstp
)
SELECT
    ItemNo,
    MIN(StartTstp) AS StartTstp,
    EndTstp
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ItemNo,
    EndTstp;
```

This produces the expected output with the sample data, I tested with additional sets of dates within 20 minutes of each other and the output was still as expected. Take note however that this only checks between 20 whole minutes and if you want to include seconds the where clause should be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` to get the previous `EndTstp`.  With this information determine when a grouping starts.  A cumulative sum of the starts defines a group . . . and then aggregation:

```
select item, min(StartTstp), max(endTstp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_endtstp >= StartTstp then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by itemno order by StartTstp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(EndTstp) over (partition by itemno order by StartTstp) as prev_endtstp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by itemno, grp
```